# Special attack blue bars

Tags: pokemon-go

Can someone please explain if the number of special attack blue lines (how quickly u can release a special attack) stay the same when you evolve a Pokemon? 
I'm hoping I'm correct in assuming the single longest blue bar gives the most power attack...
Thank you!

Comment: Please mark an answer as a solution (click on the tick mark below the answer points), so that it will help others with the same question.

Answer (score 5):

The blue bar isn't something that's related to the Pokemon. Instead, the blue bar (called as the energy bar) is the one that depends on the move you use.

Powerful moves, that hits very hard generally have a single solid bar, which means, it requires more energy and time to fill the single solid bar, but in return, it hits harder. On the other hand, the small bars does significantly less damage but fills up faster and can be used more number of times in a particular time period.

To answer your question - **NO (in most cases).** The number of bar lines doesn't stay the same as the moves changes completely after you evolve a Pokemon. If there's a move that's common between the non-evolved and the evolved Pokemon and if you've got the same move, then Yes, the bars will be the same. In short, bars are move dependent, so if the move changes, the number of bar changes according to the move.

Comment: While this is correct in explaining how the moves work, it doesn't answer the question which is specifically about evolutions.

Comment: @TimMalone Thanks for the reminder. As I was in the flow of writing, completely forgot about the question. I've edited it to now exactly answer the question asked. If there's still something missing, I'll add it.

Comment: Thank you! So I shouldn't be looking at the moves or energy bar when choosing which to evolve since they can change to anything? so therefore only focus on XP when choosing who to evolve?

Comment: @Jess Yes, exactly! It is the Pokemon IV's ([Individual Values](http://www.pokemongochamp.com/iv-in-pokemon-go/)) that matters for evolving a Pokemon and not the moves that they currently have before the evolution.   Please mark an answer as the solution.

Comment: @Jess not just the XP though - yes the highest XP will result in the highest XP for the evolved form, but not necessarily the highest XP possible in the future. So if you're playing the long game, check the IVs first :)

Answer (score 2):

The blue bar is based on the move the Pokemon has. While a pokemon's type and species determines its possible moves, they're more or less chosen randomly. An evolved Pokemon might have the same moves, or different ones.